# Redeclaring object with var

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand what is happening in the following piece of code, could anyone help? I am using node.js and I am trying to override native console (to do something else).

This works fine:

```
var output = console;
console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

And this doesn't:

```
var output = console;
var console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

I get *"cannot call method 'log' of undefined"*.

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome. Why would you want to override native `console`?

Comment: I would like to make it works with node in standard cmd. I would like to override it to add colors. For example console.info - would print in blue.

Comment: Then why not override `console.info` to print with blue? `console.prototype.info = function(){ /*your custom code*/ }`

Comment: @KevinJantzer I think you are right, your solution would be better.

Comment: @KevinJantzer there is no prototype property in node on console.

Comment: @AdrianBaran: It would have to be `Object.getPrototypeOf(global.console).info = ...`. However, this doesn't *have to* work, since `console` is a host object and can be constructed however the environment sees fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before an engine executes the code of a function (or the global context), it looks for all variable declarations, and defines the variables with the value `undefined`. That's also called *variable hoisting*.

Thus the following code:

```
var output = console;
var console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

is equivalent to:

```
var output;
var console;
output = console;
console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

And at the line `output = console;`, `console` still has the value `undefined`.

**Note:** This only happens if you are executing the code in a module or any other than the global scope. In global scope the `var console;` declaration would be ignored since the `console` is already defined in global scope.

---

If you want to create a local `console` variable *and* refer to the global `console` object, you have to reference it via the global object, which is `global` in Node.js and `window` in browsers. E.g.:

```
var output = global.console;
var console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

Comment: Variable hoisting - this is it ! Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to know why this `node -e 'var x=console,  console;x.log(1)'` correctly prints "1", while `node -e '(function(){var x=console, console;x.log(1); })();` throws a TypeError? @FelixKling

Comment: @RobW: The first is actually executed in global scope (because it's the REPL), where `console` is already defined and `var ..., console;` is ignored (`console.log(global.x)` works). I added a paragraph about that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = console;
var console = {a: 2};

output.log(console)
```

output = null because you declare console after it

Comment: if you use var console = {a: 2}; before var output = console; it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, but when the line var output = console; is reached for the first time why it doesn't use the native console object?

Comment: *"if you use var console = {a: 2}; before var output = console; it should work fine."* No, because the object doesn't have a `log` method.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `output` will never be `null` (`undefined` at most).